# How are Ethereum security bugs fixed? what is the process?

Tags: mining, bug, vulnerability

When a security vulnerability (or a high risk bug) is found in Ethereum code. What are the actual steps of detection, report, fix and deployment that are in place to resolve the issue?

Are the bugs first discussed in a special forum dedicated to such bugs?

Do the bug fixes need the vote of miners or is the miners vote only for when there is a fork? Who votes on weather the bug fix is a go or not?

Who approves the fixes that are pushed to Ethereum code base if its an emergency situation and time is a factor?